# Vertical align caret in contenteditable span (inline-block) webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, contenteditable

I have form made with contenteditable spans and my problem is that on focus my span is not vertical align better said the caret is not in the middle of span. I would like to have it in the middle and fully visible but also with scalable width so span should not be a dispaly: block neither inline.

**Picture**   : http://i62.tinypic.com/125kri8.jpg This is the issue i want it in the middle but also the caret must be fully visible

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/hqf8apwr/

**HTML**

```
 <form action="">
  <ul class=form-input>
   <li>
    <span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Vaše meno"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Spoločnosť"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Pracovná pozícia"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Telefónne číslo"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Emailová adresa"></span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
 li {
   list-style: none;
 }
 form {
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   left: -100px;
 }
 form > ul {
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 form > ul > li {
   height: 60px;
   line-height: 60px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1.2em;
 }
 form .form-label {
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 25px;
   color: black;
}
form .form-input {
   text-align: left;
   width: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
}
form .form-input li {
   height: 60px;
} 
form .form-input span {
   font-size: 1em;
   border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
   padding: 15px 20px;
   margin-bottom: -20px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   max-width: 260px;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   background: #fff;
   color: #000;
}
form .form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:focus {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1em;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 40px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: orange;
   color: #fff;
   margin-top: 2px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}
form .form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:empty::before {
   content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
form .form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
   content: '';
}
```

Comment: It is actually in the middle only... At first it seem to overflow from the span!

Comment: yes and thats the problem

Comment: Is this what you want? -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/u1ba8eve/6/

Comment: @Abhitalks my answeb is the same, but he said that this is not the problem. Awaiting a better explanation...

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Same as your answer? Where do you see `vertical-align: middle` in my fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, but I use Firefox, and in this browser don't show the orange zone. Maybe you are develop only for Chrome?

Comment: Is because of this that I don't understand correctly the problem. Sorry again

Comment: there is a orange bg in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hqf8apwr/ even on firefox BUT i understand you now ...in firefox the caret is ok so its just a webkit browser issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve some decent look by removing your fixed `height` and `padding` from the `span`. And use `padding` and/or `margin` only on `li` to control your spacing (*as suggested by Julien*). But, continue using `border-bottom` on `span` to give it a variable width effect.

***Here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/s3jmqh20/3/***

Tested in IE-11, GC-43, FF-38, and AS-5.1.7 (FF shows a vertical offset initially when content is absent, type in something and it corrects itself. No workaround for that)

This also allows you to change the `font-size` without worrying about breaking the spacing too much. Try changing the size in the fiddle/snippet.

***Snippet***:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul.form-input { text-align: left; width: 200px; list-style: none; margin-left: 12px; }
ul.form-input li { margin: 6px 0px; padding: 12px 0px; }
ul.form-input span {
    display: inline-block; color: #000; white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0px 16px; border-bottom: 2px solid orange; 
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 2em;
}
ul.form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:empty::before { content: attr(data-placeholder); }
ul.form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before { content:'\00a0 '; }
ul.form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:focus { background-color: orange; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<form action="">
    <ul class=form-input>
        <li><span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Vaše meno"></span></li>
        <li><span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Spoločnosť"></span></li>
        <li><span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Pracovná pozícia"></span></li>
        <li><span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Telefónne číslo"></span></li>
        <li><span class="input-span" contenteditable="true" data-width=30 data-placeholder="Emailová adresa"></span></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Abhitalks for your time. I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add vertical align

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

See your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u1ba8eve/2

Comment: Sorry, I edit the URL of fiddle with the property updated

Comment: but the problem is still there ... right after click before typing the caret is not center

Comment: With vertical align I see the bullet in the middle when I click and edit the content. Are you sure that you are viewing the following fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/u1ba8eve/2

Comment: That's not the answer.

Comment: the bullet isnt problem ...wait a minute pls i am going to edit the post with new demo and  with picture for better understanding

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't know what is the reason you downvote me, but in my answer is the solution. Just remove vertical align and the problem persist, just add vertical align and the problem goes away.

Comment: @JoeKoker Ok, probably I don't understand your problem. sorry if my answer is not the correct.

Comment: Now are you able to understand?

Comment: I see it vertical aligned! The "caret" is not the "bullet"? What's the caret if not?

Comment: The caret is "text cursor"

Comment: Note that in Firefox, orange box doesn't show. It's because of this that I don't understand correctly the problem. Sorry 

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to fix the caret position would be to move the padding to the `li` element. The result isn't exactly the same - the bottom border for example takes the whole width instead of only width of placeholder text and the blue outline is only on the text - but with some tweaking you may be able to get wanted result.

```
li
{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
.form-input span {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000;


  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/564hjw8w/1/

EDIT

If you want to keep an outline, you only need to give your span a width. You can also give it an offset so it has the same look as before. But note that outline-offset isn't supported by Internet Explorer

```
   .form-input span.input-span[contenteditable]:focus
{
    width: 100px;
    outline-offset: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/564hjw8w/3/

Comment: Thank you Julien for your idea but when i move padding to the list item then span after click isnt visible until typing  http://jsfiddle.net/rgqLnf0u/1/

Comment: are you using FF ? because on FF its working but not on Chrome...i found out that its webkit browser issue so it has to be problem that the span element is inline-block not a block